# Time series analysis--- dataTime

Tags: python-3.x

I'm receiving an error when I attempt to run the following Python:

```
d = datetime.strptime('2012-11-14 14:32:30.0', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

The error code is:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0
```

How to do solve this problem???

```
format = ['%d-%m-%Y %H:%M']

T = pd.Series('2019-05-23 22:47:51.541000')

T = pd.to_datetime(T, infer_datatime_format = True)
```

This is doable,, however,,

```
format = ['%d-%m-%Y %H:%M']

T = pd.Series('2019-05-23 22:47:51.541000')

T = pd.to_datetime(T, format)
```

Error Raised.

I only need the time format as 2019-05-23 22:47  ???  I have a large dataset, I cannot delete second manually!
Can anyone help me solve this issue, Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Any help ?? I am waiting!

Answer (score 0):

You're giving unexpected input with the ".0" at the end of your first timestamp.

```
d = datetime.strptime('2012-11-14 14:32:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Remove the .0 in your first timestamp; strptime isn't parsing it.

Comment: Yes, That 's from sensor data. '2012-11-14 14:32:30.03' , I read from csv file and change to time-series. But how to solve this problem, without manually correcting the 14:32:30.03 ??? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a long time, finally, i know how to do it.

```
b = datetime.strptime('2012-11-14 14:32:30.9', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

then,

```
b.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

then get rid of decimal second!!!

make sure we have, `.%f`, then there is no issue!